# I created a CRUD application that uses a @WebServlet("/") annotation, it works fine until I try add another table

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

The CRUD application works for one table perfectly but when I copy in the code for the second table, it doesn't allow me to use the same WebServlet annotation, I have tried declaring the servlet in the brackets but no luck.

WebServlet("/")

public class EventServlet extends HttpServlet {

Comment: Are you saying that you now have two servlets both listening on the same URL of `/` ? That should have produced an illegal state exception in the server logs. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Hi, ya I noticed that, I understand the issue that the two routes have the same endpoint but I just can't seem to find a solution to have both servlets operational